# Unable to pipe cmdlet objects in cmd

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

i am using this powershell command to fetch a particular user profile

"Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object {$_.LocalPath -eq 'C:\Users\Pela'}"

But when i am using this same command in cmd by invoking powershell i am getting 
'Where-Object is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file'

The command i am running in cmd is as follows :-
"powershell Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object {$_.LocalPath -eq 'C:\Users\Pela'}"

I need to run this command from cmd only , i don't have any other options .
So please give me an alternative to "Where-Object"

Comment: `powershell "powershell Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object {$_.LocalPath -eq 'C:\Users\Pela'}"`

Comment: @PetSerAl The correct answer is to [escape](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) the pipe `^|`

Comment: @DavidPostill But, if you do not use quotes, then you loose adjacent spaces: `powershell echo 'multiple   spaces'` vs `powershell "echo 'multiple   spaces'"`. And if `|` is inside quotes, then it does not need to be escaped. (It should be multiple spaces between `multiple` and `spaces`, but it seems not preserved in comments)

Comment: @PetSerAl Noted. But escaping works in this instance (where there are no multiple spaces to worry about).

Comment: using powershell "Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object {$_.LocalPath -eq 'C:\Users\Pela'}" works ...thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### So please give me an alternative to "Where-Object"

```
powershell Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object {$_.LocalPath -eq 'C:\Users\Pela
```

You don't need an alternative. The above command is failing because the pipe `|` is being interpreted by the `cmd` shell and not by `PowerShell`.

If you [escape](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) the pipe `^|` then the piping is done by the PowerShell command as expected:

```
powershell Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile ^| Where-Object {$_.LocalPath -eq 'C:\Users\Pela
```

Example:

```
F:\test>powershell Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile ^| Where-Object {$_.LocalPath -eq 'C:\Users\DavidPostill'}

__GENUS           : 2
__CLASS           : Win32_UserProfile
__SUPERCLASS      :
__DYNASTY         : Win32_UserProfile
__RELPATH         : Win32_UserProfile.SID="S-1-5-21-1699878757-1063190524-3119395976-1000"
__PROPERTY_COUNT  : 12
__DERIVATION      : {}
__SERVER          : HAL
__NAMESPACE       : root\cimv2
__PATH            : \\HAL\root\cimv2:Win32_UserProfile.SID="S-1-5-21-1699878757-1063190524-3119395976-1000"
LastDownloadTime  :
LastUploadTime    :
LastUseTime       : 20160822200129.697000+000
Loaded            : True
LocalPath         : C:\Users\DavidPostill
RefCount          : 146
RoamingConfigured : False
RoamingPath       :
RoamingPreference :
SID               : S-1-5-21-1699878757-1063190524-3119395976-1000
Special           : False
Status            : 0
PSComputerName    : HAL
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) - Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes.