# How to find out the last rebooting time of the current server in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, string, powershell, patindex, string-function

Since I already know how to [get the CPU speed of the current server in SQL Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/198065/22336) and I can find out the [last time SQL Server service started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-sys-info-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [the total RAM memory on the current server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-sys-info-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Now I would like to know when it was the last time the [current server rebooted](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-get-the-last-boot-time-with-powershell/).

This can be useful, as we do lots of [patching](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/219206/22336) of SQL Server instances.

First I started with this script - but I have some problems:

[Where-Object is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39085687/1501497)

```
 declare @sql varchar(1008)
 set @sql = 'powershell.exe -command  get-eventlog System ^| where-object {$_.EventID -eq "6005"} ^| sort -desc TimeGenerated'

 EXEC xp_cmdshell @sql
```

But then I found a better way:

```
declare @sql varchar(1008)
set @sql = 'powershell.exe -command  Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem ^| select csname, lastbootuptime'

EXEC xp_cmdshell @sql
```

Both run together, I get the following results:

[image]

Question: is there an easier way to get the last reboot time in SQL Server?

I will have to do the string manipulation, what I really really want is the yellow part below, into a `datatime2(3)` or any other SQL Server data type that I can read and convert to `datatime2(3)` or ok `datetime` would do.

[image]

Comment: In SQL Server `tempdb` is re-created everytime SQL Services restart or for the matter the box restarts. Why not just use `SELECT create_date FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'tempdb' `?

Comment: maybe `systeminfo | findstr /C:"System Boot Time"`, it returns example `System Boot Time:          17-03-2020, 9:42:26 AM` . It is probably easier to extract the date & time

Comment: SQL Server start up time does not necessary equate to box start up.

Comment: @Squirrel - My statement will be valid if SQL Services are running on the box. OP says that they do a lot of patching on SQL Instances, which makes me think that these are Production boxes where SQL Services must be running.

Comment: tempdb's created time only tells you when the SQL Service last started, which may be different than the host server that it's running on. If you have VIEW SERVER STATE permissions you can query `sys.dm_os_sys_info` to calculate the server's uptime based on the number of milliseconds reported subtracted from `getdate()`.

Comment: if SQL Server is restarted without restart the box, that will not correctly report the date

Comment: `select dateadd(millisecond, -ms_ticks, getdate()) from sys.dm_os_sys_info;` reports the same start time (within a couple of milliseconds due to latency) regardless of how often you restart the SQL Server service. [sys.dm_os_sys_info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-sys-info-transact-sql) is a DMV over operating system info data and counters.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning `ms_ticks - Specifies the number of milliseconds since the computer started.` that is the way I am going to use. Please post it as an answer and I will accept it .And thank you for this.

Comment: @squirrel - the `systeminfo` approach also works thank you